# react select load async options does not load

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to load options from backend. So i have to fetch data from API and then update options.
But i don't know how to do it. Can someone help? Here's my code:

```
function myComponent() {

  const loadOptions = () => {
    console.log('on load options function')
    axios.get(`/api/admin/roles`)
      .then((response) => {
        const options = []
        response.data.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
          options.push({
            label: permission.name,
            value: permission.id
          })
        })
        return options
      })
  }

  return ( 
    <AsyncSelect 
      isMulti 
      cacheOptions 
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
    />
  )
}
```

By the way nothing gets logged at all and that means the loadOptions function does not run. Here's my response from API:

```
response: {
  data: {
    permissions: [{
      id: 13,
      name: 'deposit'
    }, {
      id: 14,
      name: 'withdraw'
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing seems to be due to the fact that you're not returning anything at the top-level of the `loadOptions` function.

The [documentation](https://react-select.com/home#async) highlights two ways to define your `loadOptions` function.

Using callbacks:

```
const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(options);
  }, 1000);
};
```

Using promises:

```
const loadOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(options);
    }, 1000);
  });
```

In your case, it might be simplest to try the callback option first since your existing syntax is conducive with it.

```
const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
  console.log('on load options function')
  axios.get(`/api/admin/roles`)
    .then((response) => {
      const options = []
      response.data.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
        options.push({
          label: permission.name,
          value: permission.id
        })
      })
      callback(options);
    })
}
```

In the future you can optionally leverage the `inputValues` parameter to down-filter results.

Answer (score 2):

Your `loadOptions` function **must return a promise**. Also you can pass [`defaultOptions`](https://react-select.com/async#defaultoptions) as true to make the request fire for initial set of options

```
const loadOptions = () => {
    console.log('on load options function')
    return axios.get(`/api/admin/roles`)
      .then((response) => {
        const options = []
        response.data.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
          options.push({
            label: permission.name,
            value: permission.id
          })
        })
        return options
      })
  }

function myComponent() {
  return ( 
    <AsyncSelect 
      isMulti 
      cacheOptions 
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
    />
  )
}
```

**P.S** For performance reasons, you can declare your loadOptions function outside of the component so that it doesn't get recreated on every re-render

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still i can't see any options displayed

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncSelect expects a defaultOptions prop](https://react-select.com/async#defaultoptions), which you have not provided. The docs are unclear about what behavior it should exhibit in this case, but I'd guess it defaults to loading on filter.

Comment: I tested your suggestion but nothing has changes

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
const loadOptions = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/admin/roles`)
    const result = await response.data
    return await result.permissions.map((permission) => ({
      label: permission.name,
      value: permission.id
    }))
  }
```